# How to define spring-boot application properties for NON embedded servers?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application deployed on a JBoss EAP 7 server and I would like to know how to use the properties below on my server:

```
server.address=
server.port=
server.servlet.context-path=
```

As far as I know, these properties are only recognized by embebbed server's - what is not my case.

Do you guys have any idea how can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't use embedded server, you should go to JBoss EAP server administration side. I never use it but I found some documentation :

- ```
  server.servlet.context-path=
  ```

  It's generaly the name of the war file. Here the documentation for deploying a war in JBoss EAP : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/deploying_applications. In the example, the context-path is **/test-application**.
- ```
  server.address=
  server.port=
  ```

  Fot these 2 variables, you have to edit the file standalone.xml (if you are in standalone server mod of course) : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/network_and_port_configuration.

  Adress is the same than **interface**. But you shouldn't change it if you don't know what you'r doing.

  To change **port**, you have to find the line `<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>` in standalone.xml and change 8080 with you port.

Answer (score 0):

@NicolasV's answer indirectly says this, but I want to answer this question more directly.  You can't use Spring's properties mechanism to configure a non-embedded application server because in that case, the application server generally needs to be up and running before it can run your Spring app.  It is your Spring app's code that implements the Spring configuration mechanism.  So by the time your app is running, and Spring configuration is therefore available, it's too late in the server's startup process.

It would technically be possible for your application server to reach into Spring's files to use them for configuration, or to run some small part of Spring to get configuration values, but I don't see this making much sense, and I've never heard of such a thing.  So as NicolasV explains, you need to use the application server's configuration mechanism(s).